# Problema de visualización de imágenes en html y django

Tags: html, django

estoy construyendo un sitio con django, y recientemente me encontré con que no puedo mostrar imágenes en html con el servidor de django. Por ejemplo, una función simple en views.py como esta no me funciona:

```
def show(request):
    from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
    return HttpResponse('<img src="E:/Code/Django/FDTM/mysite/blog/static/blog/media/pp3.jpg">')
```

Me he asegurado que la ruta del fichero es correcta, la dirección en urlpatterns también está bien pues la pagina carga, solo que no me muestra la imagen.

Estoy utilizando Windows 10, Python 3.7.1 y Django 2.1.3

Sin embargo, cuando creo un archivo .html cualquiera con el mismo contenido del HttpResponse de arriba, me muestra la imagen. ¿Alguna idea de por qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: No debes poner la URL completa ... mysite/blog/static/blog/media/pp3.jpg solo con eso te debería de valer , porque cuando lo subas a producción te va a dar problemas

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que yo almaceno imágenes estáticas es de la siguiente forma.

1. Crea una carpeta en tu proyecto que se llame "static"
2. settings.py

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(__STATIC_PATH, "static"),
       )
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(__STATIC_PATH, 'static/')`

3.
en el template o html:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'la imagen' %}
```

Comment: falta generar la carpeta static

Comment: si, tienes razón.

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso llevo un tiempo trabajando con Django y hago lo siguiente:

1. Dentro de la carpeta raíz del proyecto creo una carpeta llamada 'static' y dentro de ella poner los archivos necesarios.( yo suelo dividirlos en 3 carpetas dentro de la carpeta 'static' css, js e imagenes)
2. Dentro de la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto habrá un archivo llamado settings.py y debajo del todo pones

   `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`
3. Después de esto y una vez guardado debes de llamar a los archivos estáticos en CADA uno de los templates en el inicio del código de esta manera:

   `{% load staticfiles %}`
4. Para llamar a cada uno de estos archivos en tu template:

   `<link href="{% static 'estilo.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>`

   - en el caso de una imagen

   `<img src="{% static 'fondo1.jpg' %}" alt="fondo">`

   - En el caso de que tengas los archivos separados en carpetas, deberás mencionar a la carpeta antes del nombre del archivo:

   `<img src="{% static 'imagenes/fondo1.jpg' %}" alt="fondo">`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo en tratar de solucionar mi problema, pero luego de mucho buscar, encontré que Django no deja servir media files subidos por la app del admin como imágenes, videos, etc sin haberle otorgado permisos antes. Necesitaba añadir en urls.py de la app que estoy usando:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [...] #aquí irían mis direcciones y al final
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
# y ahí le especifico a Django el directorio que voy a utilizar para subir
# ficheros.
```